# Efficient method to product subvectors of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose that we have a matrix

```
A = [1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6];
```

and a logical matrix

```
B = [false true ; true true ; true false ];
```

I would like to obtain the row product of elements in `A` such that the corresponding element in `B` is true.  In the example above, the answer is

```
C = [2 ; 3*4, 5] = [2 ; 12 ; 5];
```

One method would be to: 1) Take the power of `A` with respect to `B`; 2) Take the row product of the power matrix:

```
C = prod(A.^B,2);
```

The above command seems to perform unnecessary computation.  Is there a faster way of computing `C` above?

Comment: Is that really slow? That seems to be a good method.

Comment: The method above is fast, but I am wondering if there is a faster method.  I need to compute a new `C` matrix many times, so that any gain in speed would be greatly beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method seems quite fast to me. If you really have a bottleneck there, you can maybe try with cheaper operators, like addition and multiplication:

```
C = prod(A.*B + ~B, 2);
```

I only tested it with `octave`, but it's about twice as fast.

Another less compact way, also fast in `octave`:

```
C=A; C(~B)=1; C=prod(C,2);
```

Comment: `C = prod(A.*B + ~B, 2);` is about 2.5x faster than the power method.   Your second suggestion is about 1.4x slower than the power method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, using [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). I doubt it's faster:

```
[ii, ~] = find(B); % create grouping variable
C = accumarray(ii, A(B), [], @prod); % compute product of each group
```

Comment: The tilde is necessary.  Without the tilde you get the index of vectorized version of `B` rather than the column index.  This method is about 7x slower than `prod(A.^B,2)`.